# Check if authenticated user is active in session php

Tags: php, session, google-oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

Hi I am using below Login / Register systems on my website

```
1. Login via website (i.e. example.com)
2. Login via Facebook
3. Login via Twitter
4. Login via Google
```

Now when user logged in via `example.com` then i set value in session as below

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['auth_yes_exm'] = "Username from mySQL DB"
```

and when user logged in via FB,Twitter or google then i set value in session as below

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['oauth_user'] = "Oauth Username"
```

Now, there is a page `Orders` on which i check if user is authenticated then only show the order details to him / her and it is applicable as below:

```
session_start(); 
if(!(isset($_SESSION['auth_yes_exm']) && $_SESSION['auth_yes_exm']!='')){
   header('location: login.php');
   exit();
 }
```

**How can i also check that if `Oauth` user is logged in and show order detail to him as well?**

I tried as below but it redirects to `login` page always

```
session_start(); 
if(!(isset($_SESSION['auth_yes_exm']) && $_SESSION['auth_yes_exm']!='') || 
!(isset($_SESSION['oauth_user']) && $_SESSION['oauth_user']!='')){
   header('location: login.php');
   exit();
 }
```

Please get me out of this. I am setting `Oauth` session as different variable beacuse i require it to be used at some other places also.

Comment: replace your || operator with && or $_SESSION['auth_yes_exm'] set this variable too when login via FB,twitter,google

Comment: Done ... Thanks .... Sometimes mind blew like anythng... such a small change :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use

```
if($_SESSION['auth_yes_exm'] || $_SESSION['oauth_user']) {
    //Show the page
}
```

while setting whichever index you don't want to log the user in as `null` when you assign to the other index, or use this:

```
if(
    (array_key_exists('auth_yes_exm', $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['auth_yes_exm']) || 
    (array_key_exists('oauth_user', $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['oauth_user'])
) {
    //Show the page
}
```

which will avoid undefined offset warnings and require you to only define one index at a time.